# Find cell value for a row name and column name in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix M1 with 100 rows and 10 columns. I have a data frame DF with  two columns, C1 is the row names from matrix M1 and C2 is the columns names from matrix M1. Let’s say the dataframe has 10 rows with a value for C1 and C2. Using this value in C1 and C2 how can I create another column C3 which populates the cell value in M1 corresponding to the row name and column name passed from DF.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(M1)` into your post or `dput(head(M1))` if you have a large matrix. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. [Do not post images of code and/or data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434)

Comment: You should also include `dput(DF)` in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and fastest approach would be to use matrix indexing `M1[as.matrix(DF)]` (thanks @thelatemail!) followed by `diag` (Thanks @LMc!) - alternatively you could use `apply` to iterate through the rows and index on the names:

```
DF$C3 <- M1[as.matrix(DF]

# or

DF$C3 <- diag(M1[DF$C1, DF$C2]) # Thanks @LMc

# or

DF$C3 <- apply(DF, 1, \(x) M1[x[1], x[2]])
```

All give you:

```
      C1    C2  C3
1  row31 col10 931
2  row79  col5 479
3  row51  col3 251
4  row14  col8 714
5  row67  col1  67
6  row42  col4 342
7  row50  col6 550
8  row43  col9 843
9  row97  col7 697
10 row25  col2 125
```

All are likely inconsequential on small sizes, but as you scale up matrix indexing and `diag` are substantially faster:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  apply = apply(DF, 1, \(x) M1[x[1], x[2]]),
  diag = diag(M1[DF$C1, DF$C2]),
  as.matrix = M1[as.matrix(DF)]
)

# at OP sizes

# Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#     apply 109.812 112.9515 152.86578 122.8505 139.1235 2349.114   100
#      diag  16.351  19.8265  23.00454  21.3045  24.3445   80.357   100
# as.matrix  44.780  47.7325  55.75287  50.1950  57.0265  201.112   100

# increasing the size of M1 to 1000x100 and DF to 100 rows:

# Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#     apply 906.432 995.3510 1048.2169 1011.2240 1048.2835 3649.761   100
#      diag  95.543 106.5340  117.8076  116.1035  126.1500  181.857   100
# as.matrix  88.110  99.7225  108.3914  105.4260  110.7125  206.127   100

# increasing M1 to 1e5x1000 and df to 1000 rows:

# Unit: microseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean     median        uq        max neval
#     apply 42221.217 77061.174 86141.441 85400.4815 91822.973 399603.417   100
#      diag  7770.650  8795.851 10437.983  9346.9040 10064.524  57826.838   100
# as.matrix   310.851   454.179   513.652   510.9465   570.084   1143.894   100
```

Data

```
M1 <- matrix(1:1000, nrow = 100, ncol = 10,
             dimnames = list(paste0("row", 1:100),
                             paste0("col", 1:10)))
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(C1 = paste0("row",sample(1:100, 10)),
                 C2 = paste0("col", sample(1:10, 10)))
```

Comment: @LMc WOW that's so clever! added the improved code to the edit Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail and LMC - indeed matrix indexing is lighting fast compared to the original method (see edits), and much faster than `diag` when scaling up larger. Great contributions from both of you, wish I could give you an upvote!